# How hard is Ocram compared to other bosses I know?

Tags: terraria-console

I'm getting ready to fight Ocram on the console version of Terraria. I've played on PC and mobile before, so I'm familiar with the bosses in the other versions. How does Ocram compare? I want to know so that I can be properly prepared.

Comment: Are you asking because you're getting ready to fight Ocram and are trying to get a feeling of how tough the fight will be? Or some other reason? (This probably got downvoted because without context it seems like a very random question, so I'm trying to figure out what the real context is.)

Comment: im asking because i know all other bosses but now i bought console version so i want to fight him so i want to know is he stronger then other bosses to know what to use in fight

Comment: I'm guessing 1.1 bosses < Ocram < 1.2 bosses.

Comment: @iMAGEbox It is important to say such things in the question when you submit it. Asking a question without context makes it hard to help, and it makes it more likely to get downvoted or closed, because we don't know *why* you're asking the question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie ok. is question clear now?

Comment: Well yeah. You can tell because it's not closed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** I have not played Terraria on the PS3, so this answer is not first hand.

If you can beat the Twins and Skeletron Prime you should not have much of a problem with Ocram, assuming you put some time into crafting weapons/armor from the best available tier.

[LevelSave - The Toughest Bosses In Terraria](http://levelsave.com/the-toughest-bosses-in-terraria/) claims that he is actually easier than both The Twins and Skeletron prime when you its possible to fight him. Ocram is #4 on his list. The Twins and Skeletron prime are #3 and #1 respectively.

> While compiling my list there were many factors that came into
>   consideration. Should all the bosses be considered on the same scale?
>   Should they be considered equal on all fronts? In my mind that isn’t a
>   fair way to rank them, while one is playing in normal mode the gear
>   and weapons are clearly inferior to those available in hard mode. **That
>   being said I decided to consider the bosses in the time that a player
>   would first face them.**

Some more anecdotal evidence:
[A post on the Terraria forums](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/ocram-being-easy-or-difficult.100362/)

> Masamune1004 write:
>
> I can defeat him by standing in one place holding R1 and aiming up
>   with a harp in full hallowed armor, with heart statues but without
>   using meteorite/hellstone. Usually no potions either, sometimes one
>   greater health potion if the servants don't feel like dropping hearts.
>   So basically he can be defeated afk (or afc in this case :p).

Answer (score 1):

Ocram isn't too much harder than Prime until his second stage. In this stage his damage will be increased,he will shoot lasers a lot faster,and will blast you with demon sickles. I recommend at least Adamandite armor before fighting him.